# C#: Calculation using numbers larger than 3 billion is returning NaN

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm very new to C# and programming, in general. I'm trying to calculate the intersection of a line and an ellipse.
The code works as expected when the radius of the ellipse is larger than 1f.

When the radius is (approx) smaller than 1f, "t" returns NaN.

I've calculated the numbers by hand, and I noticed that when radius dips bellow 1f, B * B = 3 billion+.

I've attempted to turn "t" into a double, and I've attempted to use System.Math instead of Mathf.
"t" still returns NaN when radius < 1f.

Any feedback is much appreciated!

```
public static Vector2 GetEllipseOuterIntersection(Vector2 ellipseCentre, float radius, Vector2 lightDot, Vector2 objectDot) {

    lightDot.x -= ellipseCentre.x;
    lightDot.y -= ellipseCentre.y;
    objectDot.x -= ellipseCentre.x;
    objectDot.y -= ellipseCentre.y;

    // Get the semiminor axis.
    float vertRadius = radius/2;

    // Calculate the quadratic parameters.
    float A = (objectDot.x - lightDot.x) * (objectDot.x - lightDot.x) / radius / radius + (objectDot.y - lightDot.y) * (objectDot.y - lightDot.y) / vertRadius / vertRadius;
    float B = 2 * lightDot.x * (objectDot.x - lightDot.x) / radius / radius + 2 * lightDot.y * (objectDot.y - lightDot.y) / vertRadius / vertRadius;
    float C = lightDot.x * lightDot.x / radius / radius + lightDot.y * lightDot.y / vertRadius / vertRadius - 1;

    double t = (-B + System.Math.Sqrt(B*B - (4*A*C))) / 2 / A;

    print(t);

    float x = (float) (lightDot.x + (objectDot.x - lightDot.x) * t + ellipseCentre.x);
    float y = (float) (lightDot.y + (objectDot.y - lightDot.y) * t + ellipseCentre.y);

    Vector2 outerIntersection = new Vector2(x, y);

    return outerIntersection;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `NaN` stands for? If not, it represents a value that is not a number. and trying to assign `NaN` to a type that is a numeric type will cause an error. IMHO you could look into using [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Can you set a conditional breakpoint and backtrace why you get NaN exactly? One case mentioned in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan) is `0/0`. That could be handled separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as any component of any of your calculations is a `NaN` then the entire result will also be a `NaN`.

[`NaN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.double.nan) isn't related to the number growing to big (this would afaik either throw an exception or behave unexpected  - e.g. flipping to negative values). It rather hints that at some point of your calculations you are creating a mathematically undefined value.

> A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is undefined. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN, as the following example shows. (But note that dividing a non-zero number by zero returns either PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity, depending on the sign of the divisor.)

Besides that `3 Billion * 3 Billion` would be `9E+24`, the maximum value of `float` is `3.40282347E+38` so this wouldn't be a problem anyway.

You are probably dividing by `/ 0` somewhere

Places where this might e.g. happen are

- when you pass in `radius = 0`

  Because at a lot of occasions you are dividing by `/ radius`
- when you pass in `radius = 2`

  because then you later are doing

  ```
  vertRadius = radius / 2;
  ```

  => is 1 and then later you do `/ vertRadius - 1` e.g. for `C`

  so `vertRadius - 1` would be `0`
- if `A = 0`
- if `objectDot.x - lightDot.x = 0`

  because then `A`, `B` and `C` are all `0`
- if `B*B - 4*A*C = 0`

  because also the square-root of negative numbers is undefined and you do

  ```
  System.Math.Sqrt(B*B - 4*A*C)
  ```

You should split up your calculations and add checks to make debugging, reading and maintenance easier  e.g. somewhat like

```
public static Vector2 GetEllipseOuterIntersection(Vector2 ellipseCentre, float radius, Vector2 lightDot, Vector2 objectDot) 
{
    if(Mathf.Approximately(radius, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogError("radius may not be 0");
        return default;
    }

    if(Mathf.Approximately(radius, 2))
    {
        Debug.LogError("radius may not be 2");
        return default;
    }

    lightDot.x -= ellipseCentre.x;
    lightDot.y -= ellipseCentre.y;
    objectDot.x -= ellipseCentre.x;
    objectDot.y -= ellipseCentre.y;

    // Get the semiminor axis.
    float vertRadius = radius/2;

    var difX = objectDot.x - lightDot.x;
    var difY = objectDot.y - lightDot.y;

    if(Mathf.Approximately(difX, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogError("objectDot.x - lightDot.x may not be 0!");
        return default;
    }

    if(Mathf.Approximately(difY, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogError("objectDot.y - lightDot.y may not be 0!");
        return default;
    }

    var difXSqr = difX * difX;
    var difYSqr = difY * difY;
    var radiusSqr = radius * radius;
    var vertRadiusSqr = vertRadius * vertRadius;
    var lightDotXSqr = lightDot.x * lightDot.x;
    var lightDotYSqr = lightDot.y * lightDot.y;

    // Calculate the quadratic parameters.
    float A = difXSqr / radiusSqrInverse + difYSqr / vertRadiusSqr;
    float B = 2 * lightDot.x * difX / radiusSqr + 2 * lightDot.y * difY / vertRadiusSqr;
    float C = lightDotXSqr / radiusSqr + lightDotYSqr / vertRadiusSqr - 1;

    if(Mathf.Approximately(A, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogError("A may not be 0!");
        return default;
    }

    double BSquare = B*B;
    double AC4 = 4*A*C;
    double DIF = BSquare - AC4;

    if(DIF < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("DIF may not be negative!");
        return default;
    }

    double t = (-B + System.Math.Sqrt(DIF)) / 2 / A;

    print(t);

    float x = (float) (lightDot.x + difX * t + ellipseCentre.x);
    float y = (float) (lightDot.y + difY * t + ellipseCentre.y);

    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer! I ran many tests and the problem was in the square root. It became a negative number. This was due to my ellipse getting small, and out of the range of my lines, which was not obvious to the naked eye due to a number of reason.
I'm going to pursue other ways to tackle my particular problem, Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a long instead.

Long values go much higher than Integers.

```
// first number
long myLongNumber = 2345608830;

// second number
long secondLong = myLongNumber * 3;
```

result of secondLong: 7036826490

Edit: I didn't see you need decimals. If rounding to whole number is a problem then you might need some other solution.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue ... if numbers grow to high you would get an exception or just strange values (e.g. flipping to negative values). `NaN` most of the times rather hints to a division by `0` or any other not defined number (e.g. tangens(90°) etc)